# Why does Java require "This method can be called at most once in a given Java Virtual Machine"?

Tags: java, jvm

In Java documentation for a static method URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory, there is a warning that "This method can be called at most once in a given Java 
Virtual Machine".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory)

I briefly looked at the source code, and there is a one static instance variable in URL class:

```
static URLStreamHandlerFactory factory;
```

and setURLStreamHandlerFactory is merely assigning the factory to this variable:

```
public static void setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URLStreamHandlerFactory fac) {
    synchronized (streamHandlerLock) {
        if (factory != null) {
            throw new Error("factory already defined");
        }

        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

        if (security != null) {
            security.checkSetFactory();
        }

        handlers.clear();

        factory = fac;
    }
}
```

Allowing this method to be called multiple times would result in overwriting this factory instance variable, but I don't see WHY Java would want to prevent this behavior.

WHY does Java require that this method can be called only once per JVM?

Comment: how would we know? However, it does makse sense - usually you don't want user applications being able to override such things when defined on JVM initialization.

Comment: Well, setURLStreamHandlerFactory method is supposed to be called by User applications (I assume), but this is a weird requirement that user applications can only call this method ONCE.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to the existence and common usage of the `URLClassLoader` class.  Supposing that `URLClassLoader` ultimately depends on `URL` to retrieve data, I can imagine that allowing the stream handler factory to be redefined once set would provide a possible vector for subverting an application.

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be no precise reason.

Interestingly, the Eclipse "Runnable JAR File Exporter" functionality registers a custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` named `RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory`. 
`URLStreamHandlerFactory` itself wraps an other `URLStreamHandlerFactory` and provides a method `setURLStreamHandlerFactory` to overwrite it. Quoting from the method's [docs](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/jar%20in%20jar%20loader/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory.java):

> Allow one other URLStreamHandler to be added.
>   URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory does not allow
>   multiple factories to be added.
>   The chained factory is called for all other protocols,
>   except "rsrc". Use null to clear previously set Handler.

This `setURLStreamHandlerFactory` can be called multiple times and should provide some evidence of the fact that changing the handler should not cause any strange behaviour.

Even more Interestingly, I spotted a 1998 JDK [feature request](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4191098) on the fact that `setURLStreamHandlerFactory` should be allowed to be called multiple times so that several handlers could be chained together. The feature request was resolved as *Future Project* but evidently was never implemented.

Comment: More of a 1998 Sun JVM feature request ;) +1

Comment: @uraimo I was actually wondering how it could be an OpenJDK feature request... and in fact it is not:) I updated the post and the link, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: :) Looks like they did a mass import of all the open jdk bugs around 2012.